# NodeJS sockets.io how to create public server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Currently my server works locally, but I want to use a public IP so the app would work outside my local network. I think I need to use express and http, but I couldn't get it working because it said that port is already in use and some other errors.
Some of my code now:
index.html

```
<script defer src="http://192.168.0.17:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

client.js

```
const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.17:4000')
```

server.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(4000)
io.on('connection', socket => {...
```

Comment: Look up "port forwarding". It's exactly the same as if you wanted to host a Minecraft server.

Comment: Why not host on heroku or another free node js host?